# How to construct a std::set or Boost flat_set from objects’ data members?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector, stdset

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

class Myclass
{
    int member_a;
    int member_b;
public:
    Myclass() {};
    Myclass(int a_init, int b_init) : member_a(a_init), member_b(b_init) {};

    operator int() const {      return member_a;    }
    int get_a() const {     return member_a;    }
};

int main()
{
    auto myvector = std::vector<Myclass>({ {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0} });
    auto myset = std::set<int>(myvector.begin(), myvector.end());
    for (auto element : myset) {
        std::cout << "element: " << element << "\n";
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am constructing a `std::set` that contains only a particular data member of each object in a `std::vector`. I achieve this by using `operator int()`.

However, I dislike this solution because it is not very readable and creates potential pitfalls, and I may also want to create a set of only the `member_b` s.

Is there a way of constructing the set using `get_a()` instead of the `operator int()`, without using a loop? I’d also like to avoid creating a temporary vector that contains only the `member_a`'s.

The same issue is particularly relevant for constructing a `Boost::flat_set` which, as far as I understand, would re-sort unnecessarily if the elements are added one-by-one in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to [insert the desired members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) to `myset` instead of using `operator int()`. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7AtGuTZvRkk9H0D6))**

```
#include <algorithm> // std::transform
#include <iterator>  // std::inserter

std::transform(myvector.cbegin(), myvector.cend()
    , std::inserter(myset, myset.begin())
    , [](const auto& cls) { return cls.get_a(); }
);
```

---

Generic enough?. Okay, in order to make it more generic, you can put it into a function, in which pass the *vector of `Myclass`*, `myset` to be filled, and *the member function pointer* which needed to be called. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2t6BEfaD9m3oxNHf))**

```
#include <algorithm>  // std::transform
#include <iterator>   // std::inserter
#include <functional> // std::invoke
#include <utility>    // std::forward

using MemFunPtrType = int(Myclass::*)() const; // convenience type

void fillSet(const std::vector<Myclass>& myvector, std::set<int>& myset, MemFunPtrType func)
{
    std::transform(myvector.cbegin(), myvector.cend()
        , std::inserter(myset, myset.begin())
        , [func](const Myclass& cls) { 
               return (cls.*func)(); 
               // or in C++17 simply invoke the func with each instace of the MyClass
               // return std::invoke(func, cls);
        }
    );
}
```

Or completely generic using [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template), one could: **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9OcML0g2P9BxcQVt))**

```
template<typename Class, typename RetType, typename... Args>
void fillSet(const std::vector<Class>& myvector
    , std::set<RetType>& myset
    , RetType(Class::*func)(Args&&...)const
    , Args&&... args)
{
    std::transform(myvector.cbegin(), myvector.cend()
        , std::inserter(myset, myset.begin())
        , [&](const Myclass& cls) { return std::invoke(func, cls, std::forward<Args>(args)...);  }
    );
}
```

Now you fill the `myset` like.

```
fillSet(myvector, myset, &Myclass::get_a); // to fill with member a
fillSet(myvector, myset, &Myclass::get_b); // to fill with member b
```

---

Here is the full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>  // std::transform
#include <iterator>   // std::inserter
#include <functional> // std::invoke
#include <utility>    // std::forward

class Myclass
{
    int member_a;
    int member_b;
public:
    Myclass(int a_init, int b_init) : member_a{ a_init }, member_b{ b_init } {};
    int get_a() const noexcept { return member_a;   }
    int get_b() const noexcept { return member_b;   }
};

template<typename Class, typename RetType, typename... Args>
void fillSet(const std::vector<Class>& myvector
    , std::set<RetType>& myset
    , RetType(Class::*func)(Args&&...)const
    , Args&&... args)
{
    std::transform(myvector.cbegin(), myvector.cend()
        , std::inserter(myset, myset.begin())
        , [&](const Myclass& cls) { return std::invoke(func, cls, std::forward<Args>(args)...);  }
    );
}

int main()
{
    auto myvector = std::vector<Myclass>({ {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, 0} });
    std::set<int> myset;

    std::cout << "Filling with member a\n";
    fillSet(myvector, myset, &Myclass::get_a);
    for (auto element : myset)  std::cout << "element: " << element << "\n";

    std::cout << "Filling with member b\n"; 
    myset.clear();
    fillSet(myvector, myset, &Myclass::get_b);
    for (auto element : myset) std::cout << "element: " << element << "\n";

}
```

**Output**:

```
Filling with member a
element: 1
element: 2
element: 3
Filling with member b
element: 0
```

Comment: Indeed, `std::transform` looks like it is exactly what I was asking for, at least for `std::set`. However, how well does it work with `Boost::flat_set`? I’d be worried about the performance.

Comment: @Tim  I am not familiar with Boost::fat_set, but in the case of performance doubts, just benchmark the case with any other possible solutions what you know. Other than that, unfortunately i could not say any other options.

Comment: @JeJo `flat_set` is the api of `set` backed by a `vector` instead of a tree

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I didn't get a chance for `boost` ing my code.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `std::transform`, you can also use `boost::transform` (or it's pipe variant `boost::adaptors::transformed`), which takes the whole container, rather than it's begin and end iterator. It returns a view, which you can initialise `myset` with.

```
auto view = boost::transform(myvector, std::mem_fn(&myclass::get_a));
auto myset = std::set<int>(view.begin(), view.end());
```

You can also use `boost::copy_range` to range-construct a container from an rvalue range.

```
auto to_a = std::mem_fn(&myclass::get_a);
auto myset = boost::copy_range<std::set<int>>(myvector | boost::adaptors::transformed(to_a));
```

Comment: Looks promising to what OP wanted. +1 from me!

Comment: Haven’t tried this out but it does indeed looks like the answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like I cannot accept two answers, although both are equally valid and useful. Sorry, had to choose one and the other one was first.

Comment: @Tim no problem. JeJo's answer is much more thorough.